# How come this database is created on external storage?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I am working on some legacy code.

I have noticed that if **I uninstall the application the database does not get deleted** (when I do a select I get "old records"),

hence I have to suppose the db is created on external storage,

but I do not understand how this happens because no path for the database is given.

**Please can you help me understand what is happening???**

This is the Helper:

```
private class CustomSQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public CustomSQLiteOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String s;
        try {
            Toast.makeText(context, "1", 2000).show();
            InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(
                    R.raw.sql);
            DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                    .newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(in, null);
            NodeList statements = doc.getElementsByTagName("statement");
            for (int i = 0; i < statements.getLength(); i++) {
                s = statements.item(i).getChildNodes().item(0)
                        .getNodeValue();
                // Log.d("SQL:", s);
                db.execSQL(s);
            }
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(context, t.toString(), 50000).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS jobs");
        onCreate(db);
    }

}
```

This is the `R.raw.sql` **(the SQL statement that is executed):**

```
<sql>

<statement>
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [jobs] (
  [jobNo] TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE COLLATE NOCASE, 
  [test_id] NUMERIC NOT NULL,
  [totalqty] NUMERIC NOT NULL, 
  [testedqty] NUMERIC NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  [passedqty] NUMERIC NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  [created] TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT (datetime('now','localtime')), 
  [LastUpdated] TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT (datetime('now','localtime')),
  [LastReportedRecord] NUMERIC NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  [ReportNumber] NUMERIC NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  [active] NUMERIC NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
  );
</statement>

<statement>  
CREATE TRIGGER job_lastupdate
AFTER UPDATE ON jobs FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE jobs
SET LastUpdated = (datetime('now','localtime'))
WHERE rowid = old.rowid;
END;
</statement>

<statement>
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [recipients] (
  [email] TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE COLLATE NOCASE 
  );
</statement>


<statement>
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [test] (
  [desc] TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE, 
  [type] INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  [created] TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT (datetime('now','localtime'))
  );
</statement>

<statement>INSERT INTO test (desc, type) VALUES('Open Test', 1);</statement>
<statement>INSERT INTO test (desc, type) VALUES('Closed Test', 2);</statement>

<statement>
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [testlimit] (
  [desc] TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE, 
  [test_id] INTEGER NOT NULL,
  [seqNo] INTEGER NOT NULL,
  [s0lower] NUMERIC NOT NULL, 
  [s1lower] NUMERIC NOT NULL, 
  [s2lower] NUMERIC NOT NULL,  
  [s0upper] NUMERIC NOT NULL, 
  [s1upper] NUMERIC NOT NULL, 
  [s2upper] NUMERIC NOT NULL, 
  [stability] NUMERIC NOT NULL, 
  [created] TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT (datetime('now','localtime')),
  [modified] TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT (datetime('now','localtime'))
  );
</statement>

<statement>  
CREATE TRIGGER testlimit_lastupdate
AFTER UPDATE ON testlimit FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE testlimit
SET modified = (datetime('now','localtime'))
WHERE rowid = old.rowid;
END;
</statement>

<statement>INSERT INTO testlimit (desc, test_id, seqNo, s0lower, s1lower, s2lower,     s0upper, s1upper, s2upper, stability) VALUES('Rest', 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 25, 25, 25, 100);    </statement>
<statement>INSERT INTO testlimit (desc, test_id, seqNo, s0lower, s1lower, s2lower,     s0upper, s1upper, s2upper, stability) VALUES('Low', 1, 2, 800, 900, 900, 1000, 1100, 1100,     50);</statement>
<statement>INSERT INTO testlimit (desc, test_id, seqNo, s0lower, s1lower, s2lower,     s0upper, s1upper, s2upper, stability) VALUES('High', 1, 3, 3600, 2900, 2900, 3699, 3100,     3100, 50);</statement>

<statement>INSERT INTO testlimit (desc, test_id, seqNo, s0lower, s1lower, s2lower,         s0upper, s1upper, s2upper, stability) VALUES('Rest', 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095);    </statement>
<statement>INSERT INTO testlimit (desc, test_id, seqNo, s0lower, s1lower, s2lower,     s0upper, s1upper, s2upper, stability) VALUES('50g', 2, 2, 500, 800, 800, 1800, 3000, 3000,     100);</statement>

<statement>
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [deviceRecords] (
  [devid] TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE,
  [serial] TEXT UNIQUE COLLATE NOCASE,
  [version] TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE,
  [created] TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT (datetime('now','localtime'))
);       
</statement>

<statement>
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [testRecords] (
  [job_id] INT NOT NULL, 
  [dev_id] NUMERIC NOT NULL, 
  [zero0min] NUMERIC NOT NULL,
  [zero0max] NUMERIC NOT NULL,
  [zero0avg] NUMERIC NOT NULL,
  [zero1min] NUMERIC NOT NULL,
  [zero1max] NUMERIC NOT NULL,
  [zero1avg] NUMERIC NOT NULL, 
  [zero2min] NUMERIC NOT NULL,
  [zero2max] NUMERIC NOT NULL,
  [zero2avg] NUMERIC NOT NULL, 
  [weight0min] NUMERIC NOT NULL,
  [weight0max] NUMERIC NOT NULL,
  [weight0avg] NUMERIC NOT NULL,
  [weight1min] NUMERIC NOT NULL,
  [weight1max] NUMERIC NOT NULL,
  [weight1avg] NUMERIC NOT NULL, 
  [weight2min] NUMERIC NOT NULL,
  [weight2max] NUMERIC NOT NULL,
  [weight2avg] NUMERIC NOT NULL, 
  [test_id] INT NOT NULL, 
  [result] TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE, 
  [operator] TEXT COLLATE NOCASE, 
  [created] TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT (datetime('now','localtime'))
  );
</statement>

</sql>
```

Comment: So `DB_NAME` does not have a path? What does [getPath](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#getPath%28%29) return?

Comment: how did confirmed that db is not getting deleted. ? if application uninstall is done db will sure get deleted.

Comment: @CL. Hi CL and thanks, i get `/data/data/my packagename/databases/my application name`

Comment: Does the app even have `READ`/`WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions? Anyway, `/data/data` is internal.

Comment: Uninstall, and then [check if the internal DB file still exists](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#sqlite).

Comment: @CL. apparently Nexus 7 does not come with sqlite3 installed, I will need to find another solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a path with the name of you package under Android/data// if you save it to externalstorage. But best way is to save any DB file under your private application storage.

for above both cases at the time of uninstall the app these folder get deleted

Comment: Hi thanks, the point is that this db seems to be saved on external storage (which I am not sure i like it) but I do not understand how it happens :-(